# Alarm lockscreen notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I make an alarm clock app, and I want when my device is locked and alarm start calling see a notification like in Apple Alarm Clock. In which method is it configured?  [Apple Clock Alarm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtq4c.png)

Comment: You can send a local notification with alert and sound, but you cannot do it the exact same way as Apple as they have alot more access to the API's/SDK's than we do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not.**

That behaviour and UI are reserved to Apple Only.

There's no such API available.

I am very sorry to tell you, but its is the plain truth.